Ct lint: ignore readmes?
I use ct lint to check my helm charts.
I just figured that lint tells me that I need a version bump when I edit a readme file inside the chart.
Is there a possibility to exclude certain files from ct lint? I tried with helm ignore, which seems not to work.

According to the documentation you can use helm ignore, but you need the flag --use-helmignore which use .helmignore when identifying changed charts
